# Double any element's value that is less than controlValue. Ex: If controlValue = 10, then dataPoints = {2, 12, 9, 20} becomes {4, 12, 18, 20}

Tags: java

Hi could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong with this problem. For one of my outputs I'm getting 4,12,9,20 instead of 4,12,18,20.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentScores {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int NUM_POINTS = 4;
        int[] dataPoints = new int[NUM_POINTS];
        int controlValue;
        int i;

        controlValue = scnr.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
            dataPoints[i] = scnr.nextInt();
        }
        //my solution//
        controlValue = 10;
        for (i = 0; dataPoints[i] < NUM_POINTS ; ++i) {
            if(dataPoints[i] < controlValue) {
                dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print(dataPoints[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Or even printing the elements in the array (and the controlValue) before your solution might give you some insights on what your code does. Btw: You seem to always overwrite `controlValue` with `10` which might not be what you want

Comment: `dataPoints[i] < NUM_POINTS` looks incorrect. You should use the length of dataPoints

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
for (i = 0; dataPoints[i] < NUM_POINTS ; ++i) {
```

Should actually be:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS ; ++i) {
```

I.e: you don't want to check if the element `dataPoints[i]` is smaller than `NUM_POINTS` but only if the index `i` itself is smaller.